# Simplifying $\sin^2 (\alpha) \cos^2 (\alpha)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry

In a more complex expression, I have the term (the only one depending on $\alpha$)

$$\sin^2 (\alpha) \cos^2 (\alpha)$$

and I would like to further simplify it, if possible in either of the following two ways.

**Question 1**: is it possible that the product of the squares of sine and cosine of an angle $\alpha$ is equal to a fixed value? I have no clue about this and the equality $\sin^2(\alpha) + \cos^2(\alpha) = 1$ seems not to help.

The initial expression can always be rewritten as:

$$\sin^2 (\alpha) \cos^2 (\alpha) = \frac{1}{4} \sin^2 (2\alpha)$$

**Question 2**: is it possible to rewrite this in terms of $\sin (\alpha)$ or a single power of $\sin (\alpha)$ only? Again, I don't know how to proceed: [Sum and difference formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Sum_and_difference_formulas) would get the expression back to the beginning.

Comment: You could always write $\sin^2\alpha \cos^2 \alpha = \sin^2 \alpha - \sin^4 \alpha$, but I'm not sure if that would be OK for your purposes.

Comment: You can use Fourier transform to simplify it.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth I also guessed this and unfortunately no, it would not be enough.

Comment: "equal to a fixed value?" Certainly not in the sense that it is constant. What exactly are you after? If the answer of @MinusOne-Twelfth is rejected then there must be criteria.

Comment: @drhab I edited the question to clarify the two kinds of acceptable results.

Comment: isn't aldready simplified

Comment: When you ask for "$\sin (\alpha)$ or a single power of $\sin (\alpha)$ only," do you mean that you will only accept something equivalent to $a + b (\sin(\alpha))^n$ where $a,$ $b,$ and $n$ are constants and $n$ is an integer? If so I think you're out of luck, since your function is sinusoidal with period $\pi/2$ and the powers of $\sin(\alpha)$ all have longer periods (and mostly are not sinusoidal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow your link to the sum and difference of angles formulae, you'll see just below the double angle formulae, which are direct consequences.  One of those is

$$\cos 2x = 1-2\sin^2 x.$$

Let $x = 2\alpha$ and solve for $\sin^2 2\alpha$ to get

$$\sin^2 2\alpha = \frac{1-\cos 4\alpha}{2}.$$

Plug this into the expression you already have:

$$\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\alpha = \frac{1}{4} \sin^2 2\alpha = \frac{1-\cos 4\alpha}{8}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: It is $$\frac{1}{8}(1-\cos(4x))$$

Comment: That's the final answer, but still gives good insight to the following hint. Replace $\sin^2\alpha$ by $1-\cos^2\alpha$ (that's an identity) and use the general doubling formula $\cos(2\theta)=2\cos^2\theta-1$.

Comment: Sorry, I can't get your points. This is in terms of $4\alpha$, not $\alpha$.

Comment: @BowPark Yes, this has $4\alpha$ instead of $\alpha$ inside the trig function, but with this formula you can easily plot the function. It is a sinusoidal shape, but unlike $\sin\alpha$ you have four full cycles instead of just one between $\alpha=0$ and $\alpha=2\pi.$ One cycle goes from a minimum of $0$ at $\alpha=0$ to a maximum of $\frac14$ at $\alpha=\frac\pi4$ and back to $0$ at $\alpha=\frac\pi2.$

Answer (score 0):

You can for example use [Fourier transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) together with the [convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) to solve it and get Dr. Sonnhard Graubner's answer.

It is kind of a generalization of all the trigonometric laws.

But maybe Fourier transforms are too hard for your course?

Comment: Maybe I could try (even if this doesn't belong to the course), but... I still didn't understand what actually is Dr. Sonnhard Graubner's answer.

Comment: @BowPark A slightly easier way than to use Fourier transforms would be to use Euler formula if you have learned them in course. Like $\sin(x) = \frac{e^{xi} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$